# Converty List of Lists to Numpy Array without carrying over the list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to convert list of lists and some other number with in the lists to numpy array.

So far i have tried this but still the list carries over to the array:

```
ll = [['119', '222', '219', '293'], '4', ['179', '124', '500', '235'], '7']
arrays = np.array(ll)
```

The output is:

```
array([list(['119', '222', '219', '293']), '4', list(['179', '124', '500', '235']), '7'], dtype=object)
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
[(array([ 119, 222, 219, 293]), 4), (array([ 179,  124, 500, 235]), 7)]
```

Is there a way to do this. I have been trying to get this for the last two days.

Comment: Numpy doesn't handle jagged arrays well, and really, you shouldn't try.  It will mess things up if you try to do any actual numpy operations

Comment: Do you actually want a numpy array? Or do you want a list of tuples where the first element is a numpy array?

Comment: A list of tuples will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to group every two elements as a tuple, and then convert the first element of each tuple to a numpy array, you can use a list comprehension with **`zip`**:

```
[(np.array(i, dtype=int), int(j)) for i, j in zip(ll[::2], ll[1::2])]

# Result
[(array([119, 222, 219, 293]), 4), (array([179, 124, 500, 235]), 7)]
```

Notice that I specify a **`dtype`** in the numpy array constructor to cast the array to integers.

If you're concerned about making two copies of the list here, you can also simply use range based indexing:

```
[(np.array(ll[i], dtype=int), int(ll[i+1])) for i in range(0, len(ll), 2)]
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Casting the datatype into integers was what i wanted even though i didn't ask explicitly.  Thanks

Comment: I would also recommend looking at hpaulj's solution, because this type of grouping is usually handled using a structured array in numpy, and learning how to leverage those is a good skill to have.

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed a good skill set to have and will spend some time understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a structured array:

```
In [96]: ll = [['119', '222', '219', '293'], '4', ['179', '124', '500', '235'], '7']

In [97]: dt = np.dtype('4i,i')

In [98]: arr = np.zeros(2, dtype=dt)

In [99]: arr
Out[99]: 
array([([0, 0, 0, 0], 0), ([0, 0, 0, 0], 0)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (4,)), ('f1', '<i4')])

In [100]: arr['f0']=ll[::2]

In [101]: arr['f1']=ll[1::2]

In [102]: arr
Out[102]: 
array([([119, 222, 219, 293], 4), ([179, 124, 500, 235], 7)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (4,)), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

and extracted out to a list:

```
In [103]: arr.tolist()
Out[103]: 
[(array([119, 222, 219, 293], dtype=int32), 4),
 (array([179, 124, 500, 235], dtype=int32), 7)]
```

Or a 2x2 object dtype array:

```
In [104]: np.array(arr.tolist(),dtype=object)
Out[104]: 
array([[array([119, 222, 219, 293], dtype=int32), 4],
       [array([179, 124, 500, 235], dtype=int32), 7]], dtype=object)

In [105]: _.shape
Out[105]: (2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want individual elements to be numpy arrays, not the whole thing. So you'll have to assign those particular elements directly:

```
ll[0][0] = np.array(ll[0][0])
ll[0][2] = np.array(ll[0][2])
```

You could also loop through and find "lists" and then convert them if you don't want to write individual lines.